# How to use context manager with exceptions

Tags: python, exception, contextmanager

I need to read file attachments from email messages. I wanted to use context manager for resource management (connection should be closed)

```
@contextmanager
def some_f():
    conn = None
    try:
        for _ in xrange(CONNECTION_ERRORS_MAX):
            try:
                conn = POP3(self.pop3_host)
                conn.user(self.pop3_user)
                conn.pass_(self.pop3_password)
                logger.debug('connected {}', conn.getwelcome())
                _, msg_ids, _ = conn.uidl()
                yield (
                    (msg_id, self.files_from_msg(conn, file_batch_id, msg_id))
                    for msg_id, file_batch_id in
                    (ul.split(' ') for ul in msg_ids)
                    if not self.is_ignored(file_batch_id, msg_id)
                )
            except socket.error as e:
                if e.errno == errno.ECONNREFUSED:
                    pass
                else:
                    raise e
    finally:
        if conn:
            conn.quit()
```

So what this function supposed to do is try to connect to a email server, retry n-times if connection was refused if another socket error have happened then reraise it. If retry attempts are exhausted then reraise connection refused error. After the consumer would consume all files close connection.
Right now it gives generator didn't yield error.

Comment: Is that the `contextlib.contextmanager`?

Comment: If you read the [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextmanager#contextlib.contextmanager) for `contextmanager`, you'll see that the manager function should first perform some setup action, then yield to the 'client' code (ie. the block after the with statement), and then perform some cleanup; the `with` statement is essentially a way of sandwiching code within some predefined before-and-after logic. In your case, the yield statement is inside a `for`-loop, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: You should show how you intend to use that context manager.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your try-except clause so that it surrounds the minimum number of things.  In the except clause, you can `continue` if necessary, and if it is not triggered, you should `break` from the for loop.